Does $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) - f(x) = f(y)-f(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)$ imply that $f$ is affine?
If possible, I would like to find a convex set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) - f(x) = f(y)-f(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)$ for all $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $x,y\in X$ but is not an affine function.
Affine would mean that $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y)=\alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y)$ holds for all $\alpha\in (0,1)\text{, } x,y\in X$. Then the above condition follows immediately.

Assuming that $f$ is continuous, it must be affine.
Take $x,y\in X$. Define $g(\alpha)= \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)$ and $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)$. Picking $\alpha=1/2$ on the condition given we get $$f(x/2 + y/2) - f(x) = f(y)-f(y/2 + x/2)\implies f(x/2+y/2)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
So $$h(1/2)=g(1/2)$$
Analogously, one can show that $$h(1/4)=f\left(\dfrac{y+\frac{x
+y}{2}}{2}\right)=\dfrac{f(y)+f(\frac{x+y}{2})}{2}=\dfrac{1}{4}f(x)+\dfrac{3}{4}f(y)=g(1/4),\\h(3/4)=f\left(\dfrac{x+\frac{x
+y}{2}}{2}\right)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(\frac{x+y}{2})}{2}=\dfrac{3}{4}f(x)+\dfrac{1}{4}f(y)=g(3/4),$$
and so on.
This means that $g$ and $h$ agree on the set of all $\alpha$ of the form $\alpha=\dfrac{k}{2^n}$ with $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\leq 2^n$.
But the set of all these  $\alpha$ is dense on $[0,1]$, so by continuity $h$ and $g$ must agree on $[0,1]$, implying that $f$ is affine.
